# Access to inherit class attribute from DQL in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have an abstract class Product and inherited class ProductWithRecurrency:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name= "product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Repositories\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="product_kind_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "ProductFoo", "2" = "ProductWithRecurring"})
 */
abstract class Product
{

}


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_with_recurring")
 * @ORM\Entity( repositoryClass ="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Repositories\ProductRepository")
 */
class ProductWithRecurring extends Product
{
    /**
     * @var Recurring $recurring
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recurring_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $recurring;
}
```

I need to get some mixed Products and have "Recurring" Entity information when Product is instance of ProductWithRecurring. I have a method in ProductRepository with this dql:

```
$dql = "SELECT p product
        FROM Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product p
        LEFT JOIN p.recurring rc
        WHERE p.some_conditions";
```

Obviously get this exception:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 1182 near 'rc
': Error: Class Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product has no association named recurring
```

**Do I should add complexity to query or I have a conceptual error?** (I'm no expert in Symfony and less in Doctrine).

There may be errors in the code, I've simplified it to isolate the problem.

My english is not so good, I hope you understand me, thanks!

Comment: By the moment I added recurring attribute at the top class. No quite right but it works.
Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access all of the Product atributes in Product ProductWithRecurring.

Using code below does not work? I do not quite understand what you'd like to get as a result

```
$dql = "SELECT p
    FROM Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductWithRecurring p
    WHERE p.some_conditions";
```